# Rendering issue with checkboxes and multi-selects components in PrimeVue

Tags: primevue

I am new to Primevue and in my project I am getting weird rendering issue with check-boxes and multi-selects.
After checkbox or multi-select is selected checkbox-box is shrinking and second check-mark shown.
[Checbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RQ6C.png)

Also, I noticed that `data-pc-section-box` is missing `p-checkbox-box` class. I believe that is what causing this issue, but I am not sure how to fix it.
[Missing p-checkbox-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4YIb.png)
I am using Primevue `3.50.0`.
Can someone please help me with that?

Thank you in advance.

As I said, I am new to Primevue, so not really sure where to start fixing this.